# setOnKeyListener onKey not working with Eclipse/ADT Android Virtual Device - Nexus One

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt, onkeydown

Below is the code I'm using.
When the Enter key is pressed, it intercepts (consumes) the key press and clicks an on-screen button instead.
It works fine on my Motorola Android phone, with both the hardware keyboard and the on-screen keyboard.
It also works fine on the Galaxy Nexus Android Virtual Device in Eclipse/ADT.
But it doesn't work on the Nexus One Android Virtual Device in Eclipse/ADT.
Anyone know why that might be?
I'm worried that someone with a Nexus One will download my app and it won't work.

PS: I've also tried several other onKey methods (using onKeyUp, onKeyDown and ACTION_UP) and none of them worked with the Nexus One.

```
   MyEditText.setOnKeyListener(new EditText.OnKeyListener() 
   {
      public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
      {
         if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER))
         {
         MyButton.performClick();
         return true;
         }
      return false;
      }

   });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   MyEditText.setOnKeyListener(new EditText.OnKeyListener() 
   {
      public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
      {
         if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) || (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER))
         {
         MyButton.performClick();
         return true;
         }
      return false;
      }

   });
```

Maybe you should try with `||` instead `&&`

Comment: It's not so much that this particular bit of code isn't working, but rather than none of the onKey related options (that I've tried) are working on the Nexus One virtual device even though they're working fine on the other devices. I tried your suggestion anyway though. No luck unfortunately. Thanks though.